# Linq grouping by sublist of entity which could be empty

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, grouping

I have a question regarding linq.

```
class Parent
{
    int ParentId {get; set;}
    string WhyNoChildren {get; set;}
    List<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

class Child
{
    String Name {get; set;}
}
```

Parent table:

```
ParentId | WhyNoChildren
     123 | ""
     567 | ""
     421 | "No Kids Cause of No Money"
     543 | ""
```

Child table:

```
FK_ParentId | Name
        123 | "Tom"
        567 | "Jessy"
        543 | "Bob"
```

I want to group by Child.Name, but I need to consider that a Parent has no Children. In this case my Result should be the Parent.WhyNoChilden.

E.g. the result should look like:

```
ParentId | Child.Name 
     123 | "Tom"
     567 | "Jessy"
     421 | "No Kids Cause of No Money"
     543 | "Bob"
```

Any suggestions how the linq query should look like?

Thanks and regards,
Rayk

Comment: so you basically want to reverse the relationship between Children and Parents? Meaning something like `Dictionary<Child, List<Parent>>` or `Dictionary<string, List<Parent>>` would be the result?

Comment: The result will be a list of pocos (List<Result>) for binding to ReportViewer control.

Comment: that's not really answering my question. If you want to GroupBy children, the value of the Group would be the Parent objects. Or I'm completely misunderstanding your question

Comment: @Rayk - Your question is really confusing. If you have provided the expected output you should also show the input first.

Comment: Yep thats correct. I just removed some other properties like Name of the Parent which would be also included. But ur right, the value would be the Parent. I am grouping the by Child as the same Child could be referenced by other Parent-Objects. E.g. mother/father. Maybe that was not told...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
var group =
    parents
    .SelectMany(x => 
        x.Children
        .Select(y => y.Name)
        .DefaultIfEmpty(x.WhyNoChildren)
        .Select(y => new { ParentId = x.ParentId, ChildName = y}))
    .GroupBy(x => x.ChildName);
```